# canonical and place in country

Tags: seo, canonical-url, internationalization

I have a website that is divided for the UK, thus I have it as for the UK in its entirety I have it as:

`example.org/index.php` << parent site

`example.org/england/index.php` << child pages
`example.org/scotland/index.php` << child page
`example.org/wales/index.php` << child page

The child pages have the same content as the parent except the child pages have the word "england" mentioned throughout or "scotland" mentioned throughout or "wales" mentioned throughout.

In the parent site (`https://www.example.org/index.php`) I have set the canonical as:

```html
<link rel='canonical' href='https://www.example.org/index.php'/>
```

For the child sites, I have set it as:

*For "england":*

```html
<link rel='canonical' href='https://www.example.org/england/index.php'/>
```

*For "scotland":*

```html
<link rel='canonical' href='https://www.example.org/england/index.php'/>
```

*And for "wales":*

```html
<link rel='canonical' href='https://www.example.org/wales/index.php'/>
```

**Do I need to tell Google anything else for my canonical to run successfully?**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to implement `hreflang` to define the region and language. [Learn more about it here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en).

I will also sugest that children for child pages be like

`example.org/scotland/index.php` << child page
`example.org/scotland/wales/index.php` << child page

Nothing that important, is just a preference.

Comment: thank you,
all reagions are in english, just different parts of the country.

Comment: I think `/scotland/` and `/wales/` would be separate. Why would you lump them together?

Comment: @AndrewLott it’s just a preference

Comment: Myself personally I would keep them seperate, aka

    /scotland/ and /wales/
    rather than
    thanexample.org/scotland/wales/index.php

As Wales is not in Scotland and both words Wales and Scotland are keywords I would be used to seperate the pages and optimise each page as per specific region.